# Is every acyclic graph 2-colorable?

Tags: graphs, colorings

Every acyclic graph can be transformed structurally to a tree. Therefore, every node on odd numbered levels can be colored with color $X$ and every node on even numbered levels can be colored with color $Y$. Is the reasoning valid?

Comment: Yes, the reasoning is valid. As a clarification, every acyclic graph is a tree, no conversion is needed.

Comment: An acyclic graph is a tree iff it is connected. More generally, it is a *forest*.

Comment: Valid but not really needed. If your graph has by hypothesis no cycles, it is trivially bipartite.

Comment: "Every acyclic graph can be transformed structurally to a tree." No, every acyclic graph _is_ a tree or a union of trees. That's the definition of tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An acyclic graph, usually known as a *forest*, is a collection of disjoint trees. It is only a tree if it is connected. Since trees are 2-colorable (for the same reason you mention), it follows that forests are also 2-colorable.

It is also possible to reduce the general case to the connected case: given a forest, you can join the different connected components to form a tree. The resulting tree is 2-colorable, and the same 2-coloring is also valid for the original forest.