# Tree with alternating types of nodes

Tags: terminology, trees

Suppose that I have a tree where each node is either of type `A` or type `B`.

Nodes of type `A` have outgoing edges only to nodes of type `B` and vice versa.

Is there a name/term for this kind of a tree?

A concrete example of such a tree would be the state tree of a 2 player game (like tic-tac-toe) which has alternating levels of states where it's `X`'s turn or `Y`'s turn.

Comment: In computing model, there is an ATM (Alternative Turing machine) which has some similarity to the above definition of the tree. In this model, every node has either existential type or universal. The machine has no transition rule between nodes with the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Such a tree would be *2-colored*.

Note that all trees are *2-colorable*; a *2-colored* tree is just one where the coloring's already happened.

Comment: Sadly this term isn't extendable to more than 2 alternating types (e.g. nodes of type A connected to those of type B connected to those of type C connected to those of type A)

Answer (score 0):

All trees (and forests) can be 2-colored. However there are even additional kinds (e.g. with balancing conditions).

[Is every acyclic graph 2-colorable?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71048/is-every-acyclic-graph-2-colorable)